# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS compass run from another user

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, ownership, groups, multiple-users

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 VM and 3 users (root, prod, git)

```
prod$ groups
prod

git$ groups
git prod
```

I have installed ruby on the VM for every user and ran `source /home/prod/.rvm/scripts/rvm` so I could run 'compass' from every user (including root).

I have one python script which will use compass and it's located in /home/prod/my-compass-script

The thing that I don't understand is that if I run any of these commands:

```
git$ python /home/prod/my-compass-script

prod$ python /home/prod/my-compass-script

root$ python /home/prod/my-compass-script
```

everything is fine, but if I run this command

```
git$ sudo -u prod /usr/bin/env python /home/prod/my-compass-script
```

then I get

```
Could not run compass: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

and this is the error I would get if compass wouldn't be installed.

What am I missing ? :)

P.S. The user git has sudo rights. If I run

```
git$ sudo -u prod python --version
```

everything works fine, I get the correct answer.

**EDIT 1:**
An easier question but similar to what I want to unterstand:

Why does these 2 commands return different outputs ?

```
prod$ echo $PATH

git$ sudo -u prod echo $PATH
```

Comment: `sudo` resets the environment by default. Check out the `-E` option.